# insert authorizer value through javascript spservices sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I am using SPServices to update data into List. In the List I have `authorizer` field is there. So I want to insert this field through JavaScript using SPServices. I am unable to insert that value.

```
    function ApproveUpdateListItem(itemID,SaveData,selectedVal)
var splitval=SaveData.split(",");
var radiovalues=selectedVal.split(",");
$().SPServices({
operation: 'UpdateListItems',
async: false,
listName: "Student_OnBoarding", 
updates: '<Batch OnError="Continue">' + 
         '<Method ID="1" Cmd="Update">' +
'<Field Name="ID">' + itemID + '</Field>' + //Specifying the item id is very important here  
'<Field Name="GENDER">'+radiovalues[0]+'</Field>' +
'<Field Name="MARTIAL_x0020_STATUS">'+radiovalues[1]+'</Field>' +
'<Field Name="AUTHORIZER">'+radiovalues[2]+'</Field>' +
'</Method>' +
         '</Batch>',
completefunc: function(xData, Status)
{
            //alert("Sending the xml request to the server was: " + status);
            alert("Sharepoint processing of the message returned: " + xData.responseText);
            //alert("Updated Successfully");
            var error=xData.responseText;
            var finderror=error.search('<ErrorCode>0x80020005</ErrorCode>');
            if(finderror=="-1" &&error!="")
            {
            alert("Updated Successfully");

            var SPurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;
            window.location=SPurl +"/_layouts/15/DemoEventHandler/HandleSendToApproverClick.aspx?ID="+url3[1]+"&ActionID=0&listID="+url3[1];
            //window.location=SPurl +"/Lists/Student_OnBoarding/Inputter.aspx";
            }
            else
            {
            alert("There are Some Errors or Junck Charecters in Data,Please Check All Entire Data");
            }
}
});  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update list item using

```
$().SPServices({
  operation: "Student_OnBoarding",
  async: false,
  debug:true,
  listName: "Sales Opportunities",
  ID: itemID ,
  valuepairs: [["Gender", radiovalues[0]],["MARTIAL_x0020_STATUS", radiovalues[1]],["AUTHORIZER", "-1;#" + loggedInUser]],
  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    alert(xData.responseText);
  }
});
```

You can populate `loggedInUser` using

```
loggedinUser = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(
{
    fieldName: "Name",
    debug: false
});
```